# React Navigation: navigate from children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am in a situation where I need to navigate from a child of `StackNavigator`. How is this typically achieved? Does the `this.props.navigation.navigate` have to be passed down as props or is there another way to do it? Something along the lines of React Router's `withRouter` HOC?

Comment: you can directly navigate to `this.props.navigation.navigate(SCREEN_NAME)` I guess

Comment: It's not really possible if the component doesn't have the `navigation` prop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The navigation prop is only available for the navigation-aware components which are the 'screen's. You can pass the navigation object down to child components as props or you can add the child component as a screen to the StackNavigator.

Comment: I see. A shame that that is the way to do it. The `withRouter` HOC in React Router is a life saver.

Comment: I suppose that connecting React Navigation to Redux could solve the problem, though?

Comment: Yes but I don't prefer it because it makes things more complicated. See : https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2003

Comment: I see. Thank you!